# How to set background image for only one TabItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I have TabBarController with some TabItems.

To get access for first TabItem I use:

```
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
```

How I can set background image for only this TabItem when it is selected?

The common solution is:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];
```

I tried:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar.item1 setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];
```

And:

```
[item1 setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS 7 and later, you can set Tab bar item's image and selected image by

```
    //Normal Image
    [item setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-bg.png"]];

    //Selected Image
    [item setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];
```

Comment: It sets main image, but not background oа whole tab

Comment: I tried also:  `item1 = [item1 initWithTitle:nil image: nil selectedImage:restaurantsIconImageActive];` It displays empty tab

Comment: Oh, Sorry I missed the Background image part of your question. Have you tried `[self.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];`   instead of     `[self.tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];`

Comment: Update your answer please